# Eigen: I need to define a matrix with a defined size - not Dynamic (not heap) but Fixed size (on Stack)

Tags: c++, matrix, stack, eigen

I am trying to do this type of declaration (I am a newbie in C++):

```
// Fixed Sized Matrix: you know what is the size of the matrix
#include <Eigen/Dense>
static int rows = 5, cols = 6;
Matrix<float, rows, cols> f1;
std::cout << "matrix f1: [" << f1 << "]" << std::endl;
```

but am getting an error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2975   '_Rows': invalid template argument for 'Eigen::Matrix', expected compile-time constant expression   readEigenMatrix C:\Users\xxxxxx\repos\readEigenMatrix\main.cpp  87

... and sorry if I am asking a trivial question.

Comment: `static int rows = 5, cols = 6;` are not compile-time constants even if you never change them. See if `static constexpr int rows = 5, cols = 6;` solves the problem

Comment: Just `const int rows = 5;` should suffice in this case, if you don't have C++11. The `static` is not necessary in any case. Also, you should generally post a [mre] (something one can just copy+paste+compile to reproduce the issue).